# Silent authentification with oauth2 (prompt=none)

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, wso2

Hi I have SPA(Single page application) where I use oauth2 implicit grant for authorization. As Identity server I have Wso2 identity server 5.4.1.

I am able to authorize the app and everything works as desired - also I configured to skip the consent.

Here goes the problem:
I am trying to silently reauthenticate logged user with following link with help of .../oauth2/authorize service and attribute prompt=none:

```
https://xxx:9447/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token token&nonce=123&prompt=none&client_id=xxxx&scope=openid&redirect_uri=http://localhost:63342/myapp/www/index.html&id_token_hint=previous_user_token
```

With promp=none as written here:

http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthorizationEndpoint
 I should be able to authenticate user when he is logged and the consent is configured to be skipped or always approve.

But I always get the same error back in URI:

```
http://localhost:63342/myapp/www/index.html#error_description=Authentication+required&error=login_required&session_state=state124124125125.1251512
```

Comment: I guess WSO2 uses cookies as a session indentifier, have you checked there is a correct cookie sent with the `/authorize` request?

Comment: Maybe you must pass client_id and secret on header ?

Comment: @Max nope, Client secret is something what you do not store on client side of SPA app. It would be insecure

Comment: Alternatively, you can use signinSilent(). check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63609654/6363952

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error login_required means that your user is not logged in on the IP. You must first ask him to connect by redirecting it to the authorization endpoint without the prompt parameter set to none.

See : http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthError

> login_required
> The Authorization Server requires End-User authentication. This error MAY be returned when the prompt parameter value in the Authentication Request is none, but the Authentication Request cannot be completed without displaying a user interface for End-User authentication.

According to the documentation, it seems that the user must choose the option on the consent page: Approve Always. Have you tested with this option?

Docs: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Basic+Client+Profile+with+Playground

> Click **Approve** to provide consent to this action. The screen mentions
> the service provider by name and requests for user consent to provide
> user information to that particular service provider. The user can
> either  **Deny** to provide information to the service provider. Approve
> to provide user profile information to this service provider only for
> this time.
>
> **Approve Always** to provide approval to share user profile
> information with the service provider even in the future without
> prompting for consent again.

Comment: Hi I have written that I have configured consent to be skipped which means always approve... and user was already logged in when I try to reauthentifiicate...

Comment: Yes, the problem was with consent needed to be set approve always