# Auto-Login with PKCE Code Flow using angular-auth-oidc-client

Tags: angular, oauth, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, pkce

I am implementing the auto-login concept with the PKCE Code Flow using [this npm package](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client). I tried following the documentation and example as best as I could. In my app.component.ts constructor I have the following:

```
if (this._oidcSecurityService.moduleSetup) {
        this.doCallbackLogicIfRequired();
    } else {
        this._oidcSecurityService.onModuleSetup.subscribe(() => {
            this.doCallbackLogicIfRequired();
        });
    }
```

In my ngOnInit I have the following:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this._oidcSecurityService.getIsAuthorized().subscribe(auth => {
        this.isAuthenticated = auth;
        if (!this.isAuthenticated)
            this._router.navigate(['/autologin']);
    });
  }
```

and in the method `doCallbackLogicIfRequired()` I have:

```
private doCallbackLogicIfRequired(): void {
      this._oidcSecurityService.authorizedCallbackWithCode(window.location.toString());
  }
```

And since the login page (and button) are located on the identity server (STS server), I have an auto-login component in my angular application which looks like this:

```
constructor(private _oidcSecurityService: OidcSecurityService) {
    this.isAuthorizedSubscription = this._oidcSecurityService.onModuleSetup.subscribe(() => { this.onModuleSetup(); });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this._oidcSecurityService.moduleSetup) {
      this.onModuleSetup();
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.isAuthorizedSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  private onModuleSetup() {
    this._oidcSecurityService.authorize();
  }
```

So my understanding and based on debugging the flow happens as follows:

1. The user logs in from the STS server and gets redirected to the angular app and comes immediately
   to the app component
2. The first thing it does in the app component is call the `doCallbackLogicIfRequiredMethod()` and in
   turn, that calls the `authorizedCallbackWithCode()` method.
3. Then it moves on to the ngOnInit (of the app component), which checks if the user is authorized, and since we are logging
   in for the first time, he/she is not, so it routes over to the auto-login component which calls
   the `oidcSecurityService.authorize()` method.

So, now this is where I am having some issues and am not sure what is happening.

4. So immediately after calling the `oidcSecurityService.authorize()`
   method (int the auto-login.component) it goes right into the
   body of the subscribe of the `getIsAuthorized()` method located in the app component ngOnInit. Why is it
   doing this? What is causing it to hit the `getIsAuthorized()` again?

Here are the issues:

1. The `getIsAuthorized()` method is getting hit multiple times, and for some reason, it is always false,
   even after calling the `authorize()` method from the auto-login component.
2. When I have the silent renew turned on, it seems to make things even worse and calls the
   `getIsAuthorized()` even more times.

I am getting all strange issues/errors with identity server after this is happening and I assume it is because of this `getIsAuthorized()` method and maybe my understanding of where and when to actually use it.

Questions:

1. For implementing this flow with an auto-login, am I taking the correct approach based on my example
   code?
2. Can someone explain when the `getIsAuthorized()` subscription is supposed to be called? Do other
   methods in the library maybe call it behind the scenes and that is why it is getting called multiple
   times for me?
3. I seem to be getting intermittent errors - *invalid nonce* and *invalid state*, why would this be
   occuring (I read that this could happen when the `authorize()` method is called more than once, but I only have one call to it in the auto-login.component)?
4. Just for my sanity and so I can understand the flow a little better, what is the purpose of the
   `authorizedCallbackWithCode()` method where does it go, does it return to anywhere (is there an event handler for it i should be subscribing to)?
5. Also is the silent-renew logic supposed to call the `authorize()` method? It seems to be doing that somewhere behind the scenes - 
   I noticed that before i call the `authorize()` method (from the auto-login component), the
   `authorizationResultComplete` event handler is triggered without me ever calling `authorize()`. Is this the
   expected behavior for the silent-renew, should it disrupt my application by doing this, I thought it should do everything behind the scenes (silently)?

I have been really struggling with this issue, if anyone has successfully implemented this flow using angular 2+ with this library, any help would be appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: Do not ask too many questions in one question. Try to split them in seperate questions.

Comment: @Ruard van Elburg very useful intervention for a legit post by the OP. Thanks a lot for your deep insights

Comment: Anyone who uses just oidc-client library, you can use signinSilent(). check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63609654/6363952

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are a way ahead of what it's currently supported by most authentication servers. I will suggest that you implement the simple example that is 100% compatible with oidc pkce flow: [authorization code flow + PKCE](https://github.com/scottbrady91/Angular4-OidcClientJs-Example); I tried to implement the same pattern you described above; but that logic was designed for implicit flow and it seems that is not compatible with the response received from authentication server.